# useEffect runs forever

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am a newbie to React.js.
I have a question about useEffect today.
I know that if I pass an empty [] as a second parameter, useEffect only runs once.
But, my app runs too often and if I console.log(something), I can see  that. Here is my code. Please look at line 19. [] is there. I tried to add quizzes in [] like [quizzes].

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { doc, collection, onSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore';

import db from '../firebaseConfig';

const Quiz = () => {
  const [quizes, setQuizes] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const collectionRef = collection(db, 'quizes');
    const unsub = onSnapshot(
      collectionRef,
      snapshot => {
        setQuizes(
          snapshot.docs.map(
            doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
          )
        );
      },
      []
    );
    return unsub;
    // getData(): run once
    // onSnapshot(): listen for realtime updates
  });

  console.log(quizes)

  return (
    <div className='quiz'>
      {quizes.map(quiz => (
        <div key={quiz.id} className='quiz'>
          {quiz.correctAns}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Quiz;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo where you have misplaced the empty array and passed it into the `onSnapshot()` call instead of the `useEffect()` call.

In addition, you should make sure that you attach listeners to both of the `onSnapshot`'s events - `next` and `error`. When you don't use an observer object like shown below, these are the second and third arguments to the [`onSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#onsnapshot_3) call.

```
// the recommended onSnapshot form in React
const unsub = onSnapshot(
  ref,
  {
    next: (snapshot) => { /* ... */ },
    error: (err) => { /* ... */ }
  }
);
// OR, the more confusing as your handlers grow in size:
const unsub = onSnapshot(
  ref,
  (snapshot) => { /* ... */ },
  (err) => { /* ... */ }
);
```

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    const collectionRef = collection(db, 'quizes');
    const unsub = onSnapshot(
      collectionRef,
      {
        next: (snapshot) => {
          setQuizes(
            snapshot.docs.map(
              doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
            )
          );
        },
        error: (err) => {
          // don't forget error handling! e.g. update component with an error message
          console.error("quizes listener failed: ", err);
        }
      }
    ); // <-- not here
    return unsub;
    // getData(): run once
    // onSnapshot(): listen for realtime updates
  },
  [] // <-- empty array goes here, not in onSnapshot
);
```